# checkbox not stored on database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, orm

section_controller:

```
def save
    @section =Section.new(require_section)
    @section.user_id = @level.id
    if @section.save
        flash[:notic]='post created'
        redirect_to :action=>'index'
    else
        render :action=>'create'
    end

end

def update

@section= Section.find(params[:id])
  if @section.update_attributes(require_section)
  flash[:notic]='post updated'
  redirect_to :controller=>'admin',:action=>'index'
  else
  render 'edit'
end
private

    def require_section
        params.require(:section).permit(:title, :tag, :visible, :content,:short_content,:teaser,:category_ids)
    end
```

create.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for :section,:url=>{:action=>'save'} do |f| %>

Title:<%= f.text_field :title ,:class=>'form-control'%>
.
.
.
 <% Category.all.each do |cat| %>


<%= check_box_tag :category_ids,cat.id %>
<%= cat.name %>
<% end %>
<%= submit_tag 'submit',:class=>'btn btn-success'%>
<% end %>
</div>
```

model:

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :section

end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :categorizations
has_many :sections, :through => :categorizations
end

has_many :categorizations
has_many :categories,:through => :categorizations
```

after submit form category not stored on database but post created successfully

i checked database and category_ids column has empty string

also i follow up this [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many)

Rails: 4
Database: `postgresql`

Comment: You show your code just fine, but you might explain a bit more verbose as to what is your actual problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your checkbox tag should be :

`<%= check_box_tag "section[category_ids]", cat.id %>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
<% Category.all.each do |cat| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "section[category_ids][]", cat.id %>
    <%= cat.name %>
<% end %>
```